# How do you hide two buttons when one button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, hide

In my text adventure game, there are two choices - 1. Pick up stick or 2. Leave it there. You can only choose one, so I'm wondering how you can hide both buttons after one is clicked. This is the current code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
var newButton1 = '<button onclick="two()">Pick up stick</button>'; var newButton2 = '<button onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
}

function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something."; 
}

function three()
{
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.";
}
</script>

<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
<button onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:255px; width:200px; margin-top:-15px;">
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px; height:600px;"><div id="c"></div><div id="b"></div><div id="a"></div></div>
```

Comment: You have a bigger scalability issue here. You need a common function that does this for you by passing parameters, instead of repeating virtually the same code for each decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give an id to these buttons, and when you click one , you hide both of 'em.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/EPKM7/

The code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
//create buttons and give id to it (btnTwo and btnThree)
var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>'; 
var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
}

function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something."; 

    //Clicked, hide both buttons
    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';


}

function three()
{
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.";
    //Clicked, hide both buttons
    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
<button onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:255px; width:200px; margin-top:-15px;">
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px; height:600px;"><div id="c"></div><div id="b"></div><div id="a"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give your buttons ID's and then set their display property to hidden:

```
function hideButtons()
{
  document.getElementById("pickUpStick").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("leaveStick").style.display = 'none';
}

function name()
{
  ...
  hideButtons();
}

<button id="pickUpStick" ... 
<button id="leaveStick" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, just as an add-on to what people already mentioned. You can use jQuery to easily do this in one line. Give the same class name to both buttons, "button-hide" or something like that. Then, call within your delete button function:

```
$(".button-hide").attr('style', 'display: none');
```